# target multiple buckets with eventarc?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, event-arc

currently we are trying to use eventarc to send us all finalized files for buckets.
this works create however, currently it looks like event-arc can only target a single bucket and we would need to enable it for every bucket on it's own. is there a way to target multiple buckets?

currently we use the following to create the eventarc trigger:

```
gcloud eventarc triggers create storage-events \
--location="$LOCATION" \
--destination-gke-cluster="CLUSTER-NAME" \
--destination-gke-location="$LOCATION" \
--destination-gke-namespace="$NAMSEPACE" \
--destination-gke-service="$SERVICE" \
--destination-gke-path="api/events/receive" \
--event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--event-filters="bucket=$BUCKET" \
--service-account=$SERVICEACCOUNT-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

the problem is, that we generate a bucket per customer, thus we would need to create the trigger for each bucket (which is a alot) is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

If you want to use the native event `google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized`, you must select one and only one bucket. Therefore, you have to create one eventarc per bucket.

If you can use the audit logs event `storage.objects.create`, you have to activate the audit logs but you are not filter on the buckets. ALL the buckets are listen. If you don't want, you can play with the [Cloud logging router](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview) to discard the logs that you don't want (especially the audit logs on the buckets that you don't want)

A latest solution, if you really want to use eventarc, especially for the Cloud Event format of the messages, you can do that:

- Create a Coud Storage [PubSub notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) for all your bucket that you want to listen. Use the same PubSub topic everytime
- Create a Custom eventarc on PubSub and catch the message published on the Topic.